# Cómo puedo conectar oracle sql developer a un contenedor de docker de Oracle database

Tags: oracle, docker, oracle-sqldeveloper, docker-compose

tardes o noches estoy experimentando con Docker y Oracle y tengo problemas para conectar Oracle SQL Developer a mi contenedor de Docker que está corriendo Oracle database engine, que ajustes adicionales puedo o debo realizar para que pueda conectar Oracle SQL Developer a mi contenedor de oracle database.

PD: Acá dejo mi docker-compose.yml

```yml
version: "3.9"

services:

  server:
    image: store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1
    volumes:
      - D:\DockerDataVolume\Oracle:/ORCL
    ports:
      - 1521:1521
      - 5500:5500
```

Comment: Cual sería el problema que tienes? Si el oracle funciona y están en la misma red simplemente pones localhost:1521 como ruta del oracle en el sql developer, si es otra red pones la ip que corresponda. Si esto no funciona, (y el oralce funciona) deberías probar primero la conectividad `telnet <ruta_a_oracle> 1521` desde donde está el sqldeveloper.

Comment: resultó que era un error en la configuración del puerto puente de mi equipo hacia el puerto 1521 del contenedor, junto con un enredo en los usuarios, básicamente ya quedó resuelto